# How to retrieve an object with Beautiful Soup that has several atttributes?

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, attributes

I am using the find function to retrieve this object:

```
<h1 data-testid=“organization-cover-title” class=“sc-1wcv2gl-2 kpUYKd”>Company</h1>
```

With this code below, it returns a `NoneType`

```
company = soup.find(‘h1’, attrs = {‘data-testid’:‘organization-cover-title’, ‘class’:‘sc-1wcv2gl-2 kpUYKd’}).string
```

It also does not return a string with one or the other attribute.

Would you be so kind as to find a solution?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Your example is using curly quotes in HTML and CODE that are the quotation marks used in good typography.

You have to use the straight single quote (') or the straight double quote (") to get it working in both HTML and CODE.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
html = '''
<h1 data-testid="organization-cover-title" class="sc-1wcv2gl-2 kpUYKd">Company</h1>
'''
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)

soup.find('h1', attrs = {'data-testid':'organization-cover-title', 'class':'sc-1wcv2gl-2 kpUYKd'}).get_text()
```

Answer (score 0):

The code was right actually. It works